# Accessing values from the string name of a class at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my source code for a C# class, I want to use the values of parameters defined within some other class. I want to do it without "hardwiring" the other class name into the source code (e.g., without writing something like "class2.variable").
Rather, I want to pass the name of that other class as a character string at runtime.

I am using C# within Unity. So I want to set the name of the other class as a public string within the Inspector of Unity.

For example, consider these two separate scripts:

```
using UnityEngine ;
public class ScriptA : ScriptableObject {public static int fred = 5 ;  }
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Reflection; 
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour {
    object item;
    private static string instance;

    void Start() {
        instance = "ScriptA";
        item = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instance)); 
        Type myType = item.GetType();

        foreach (FieldInfo info in myType.GetFields())
        {
            string infoName = info.Name; //gets the name of the field
            Debug.Log (" info = " + infoName);  
        }
    } 
}
```

`ScriptB` works OK ; it accesses `ScriptA` just from the string "instance", as evidenced by the fact that 
the name "fred" to appears in the console.

But how do I access the value of "fred" ; how do I make the number "5" appear on the console?
I have been trying for two days. I have searched extensively for an answer. 
Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldInfo` has a `GetValue` method :

```
public abstract object GetValue(
    object obj
)
```

Try:

```
Type myType = item.GetType();
foreach (FieldInfo info in myType.GetFields())
    {
        string infoName = info.Name; //gets the name of the property
        Console.WriteLine(" Field Name = " + infoName +"and value = "+ info.GetValue(null));  

    }
```